# How to know original variable in reference variable, possible?

Tags: lua

I got a question.

In Lua, data is dynamic type. variable assign is reference. and.. How about?

```
a = 10   -- original var. create var
b = a    -- ref
c = b    -- ref
d = c    -- ref
```

In this case, In d variable, find the original variable?

Comment: Some variables are assigned by reference, such as functions, tables, coroutines etc. Not strings and numbers.

Comment: All variables (a, b, c, d) contain ref to the same object, all they have "equal rights", no one of these variables is "the original".

Comment: if a, b, c, d is table or function then can find?

Comment: Lua debug facilities might give you an insight: https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff's answer applies to table and function values, too. No value knows what variables are referencing it. No value has a name or owner. No variable knows what other variables have the same value. A variable is assigned at runtime from the value resulting from the evaluation of an assigned expression (or passed function argument expression) with no trace of what the expression was.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I think point of that section of the Lua Reference Manual is that "copying" a mutable value results in the same object. So mutating the value via any reference to the value affects the value seen by all references. They the left the string datatype out of the list because they had already stated that string values are immutable. So, from the point of view of what a variable "contains" or is assigned, it's not really useful to distinguish between "by-value" or "by-reference" because the end result is effectively the same for all datatypes.

Comment: Although I agree with the comments; however, if you make the assumption that within the same function body, if two variables have the same type and value then the latter one could have acquired the value by an assignment from the former one. You can track variables by `debug.getlocal(1,index++)`. Again this is based on an assumption and it will fail on the condition of `a=10; b=10` such that you were assuming `a=10; b=a`.

Answer (score 2):

> variable assign is reference

Variable assignment is *assignment*. Once the assignment is done, there is no relationship between the two variables. Regardless of what is being assigned, whether it is a number or a table reference. Once the assignment is over, the two variables are no longer connected.

This is true whether they are local variables or table elements.

Comment: all variable assignment is reference. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7

Comment: @gogothing: That's not what that means. Tables are not copied; references to tables are copied. The fact that two or more variables can access the same object has nothing to do with how assignment works. If you copy a reference to a table, then both variables reference the table. The variables do not reference *each other*.